# Why does the items in my nav bar doesn't show up?

Tags: php, html, css

When I go to my home file and my header file the css works but the items in the nav bar doesn't show up, not even the image.

I tried looking for errors in my code, but to no avail.

My header file
header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- Meta tags for character set and viewport settings -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Linking an external stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- Title of the HTML page -->
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- Internal CSS styling -->
    <style>

        /* CSS styling for the logo in the left section */
        .left img{
            width: 60px;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Header section with navigation -->
    <header>
        <nav>
            <!-- Left section with logo and salon name -->
            <div class="left">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
                <h2>ILAK BEAUTY SALON</h2>
            </div>

            <!-- Navigation links in an unordered list -->
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="home.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="servicesbookings.php">Book Here</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
                </li>

                <!--<li>
                    <a href="services.php">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="payment.php">Payment</a>
                </li> -->

                <li>
                    <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my home file
home.php

```
<?php
    include("header-session.php");
?>

<!-- HTML STARTS HERE -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
     <!-- Meta tags for character set and viewport settings -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

     <!-- Title of the HTML page -->
    <title>Home</title>

    <!-- Internal CSS styling -->
    <style>
        body {
    /* Styling for the background image */
            background-image: url("images/bg.jpg");
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            height: 100vh;
            margin-top: 15%;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        /* Styling for the footer-like container */
        .container-footer {
            background-color: gray;
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            height: 10%;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
            position: fixed; 
            bottom: 0;
            padding: 10px; 
            opacity: .89;
        }
    </style>
</head>


<body>

    <!-- Footer-like container -->
    <div class="container-footer">
        <h3>A modern concept of a beauty salon and the popular feeling of a day spa.</h3>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Note that I am using session-header for the log in and log out section of my website. Just to be sure here is my session-header file

session-header.php

```
<?php
    // Include the header file
    

    session_start();
   
    if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"])){
        include("header.php");
    }else{
        include("header_signin.php");
    }
    
?>
```

Below is my CSS file

style.css

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    color: #E5E7E6;
}
body {
    background-color: #141301;
    color: #E5E7E6;     
    
}

body{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
header {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 1000%;
    z-index: 1000;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: left;
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
    padding: 20px;
}
.left {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
nav img {
    width:  0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
nav h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
nav ul li {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #6B2B06;
}
.container1 {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    padding: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.text {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 5%;
    width: 65%;
    background-color: rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.7);
    padding: 60px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.text img{
    padding: 25px;
}
.info span {
    color: red;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: block;
}
.info {
    font-size: 18px;
    
}
.info h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.info p {
   
    font-size: 30px;
    
}
.container-story{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.text-story {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 5%;
    width: 65%;
    background-color: rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.7);
    padding: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.text-story img { 
    padding: 36px;
}
.info-story span {
    color: red;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: block;
}
.info-story {
    font-size: 18px;
    
}
.info-story h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.info-story p {
   
    font-size: 30px;
    
}
.container-mission{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}
.text-mission {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 5%;
    width: 65%;
    background-color: rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.7);
    padding: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.text-mission img{
    padding: 25px;
}
.info-mission span {
    color: red;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: block;
}
.info-mission {
    font-size: 18px;
    
}
.info-mission h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.info-mission p {
   
    font-size: 30px;
    
}
.container-choose{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.text-choose {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 5%;
    width: 65%;
    background-color: rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.7);
    padding: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.text-choose img{
    padding: 25px;
}
.info-choose span {
    color: red;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: block;
}
.info-choose {
    font-size: 18px;
    
}
.info-choose h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.info-choose p {
   
    font-size: 30px;
    
}
.container-visit{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.text-visit {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 5%;
    width: 65%;
    background-color: rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.7);
    padding: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.text-visit img{
    padding: 25px;
}
.info-visit span {
    color: red;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: block;
}
.info-visit {
    font-size: 18px;
    
}
.info-visit h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.info-visit p {
   
    font-size: 30px;
    
}
```

Comment: is it `header-session.php` or `session-header.php`? Also - as `header.php` is a complete HTML page you would not want to include all of that content before beginning a new document in `home.php`

Comment: It's header-session.php sorry for the confusion. How should I go about not including all the content before beginning a new document? Sorry, I am a student so my knowledge is lacking.

Comment: Presumably you wish to include the `NAV` component in every page - so include JUST that piece of the HTML at the location in the main document you wish the NAV to appear

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that my header-session.php won't work and won't check if the person is loggedin?

Comment: Just look at the source of the generated HTML page in your browser and you will see the mess.

Comment: You will have to include the session logic before you begin the HTML page if it calls `header`

Comment: I’ll take note of all your suggestions, thank you guys!